# Laravel cannot pass multiple middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

recently i created two middlewares which is one for user called device, and one other for super user which is high level of admin. This is my middleware

Role Device Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleDevice
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role=='device'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('danger',"You don't have an access");
    }
}
```

Role Device Super User

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use User;
class RoleSuper
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role=='super'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('danger',"You don't have an access");
    }
}
```

after i created the middlewares, i put into the routes which is one route could access two middlewares. Here is one of my route.

```
Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index')->middleware(['rolesuper','roledevice'])->name('dashboard');
```

and when i try to log in into my website, it returns

```
You don't have an access
```

which is don't pass into the middleware.

i hope i get any comments above !
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Middlewares are executed in the order the are passed. So in case first middleware returns redirect response that's it - second middleware won't be executed.

You could combine both middleware into one and pass available roles as [middleware parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-parameters) or just create single middleware for this that will verify if user is authorized.